# ggplot2 is slow when adding a rectangle

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am adding a rectangle to a ggplot (geom_raster) with geom_rect. The execution take much longer compared to plotting without the rectangle.

I am trying to plot a black and white image using geom_raster. I need to display a box on top of that image. It is reasonably fast for the simple image (0.2 sec for 128*72; 2 sec for 1280*720 image). when I add a rectangle using geom_rect the times are much longer (0.6 sec for 128*72; 30 sec for 1280*720 image) [times for rd5.xlarge EC2 instance] I have reasonable experience in base R, but am new to tidyverse. Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong? I understand I can use imager to display images directly, but I would like the geom_raster.

```
## make dummy data
test_df<-t(sapply(1:1280,function (x) abs(sort(rnorm(720,mean=1280/2, sd=1280/2*0.34))-(1280/2) )) )

## rearrange data to be tidy
df_gs_tidy<-test_df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  mutate( xval= rep(1:nrow(test_img_gs), each=ncol(test_img_gs))) %>%
  mutate(yval= rep(ncol(test_img_gs):1, nrow(test_img_gs))) %>%
  rename(zval=value)

## measure time [system.time() does not accurately show the time it takes]
st.time<- Sys.time()
p<-ggplot(df_gs_tidy, aes(x=xval, y=yval)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = zval)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = grey(seq(0,1,l=20))) +
  theme_bw() + ggtitle(i) 
en.time1<- Sys.time()
p
en.time2<- Sys.time()
paste ("time1: ",round(en.time1-st.time,4),"sec")
paste ("time2: ",round(en.time2-st.time,4),"sec")
## around 2 sec on my machine

## Now with the rectangle
st.time<- Sys.time()
p<-p +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 140, xmax = 1140,
                ymin = 300, ymax = 420), 
            fill=NA, color="red", size=0.5)
en.time1<- Sys.time()
p
en.time2<- Sys.time()
paste ("time1: ",round(en.time1-st.time,4),"sec")
paste ("time2: ",round(en.time2-st.time,4),"sec")
## around 22 sec on my machine
###################
## We can reduce the dataset, but the effect remains
xval_red<- seq(1,max(df_gs_tidy$xval), by =10)
yval_red<- seq(1,max(df_gs_tidy$yval), by =10)
df_gs_tidy_plot<-df_gs_tidy %>%
  filter(xval %in% xval_red, yval %in% yval_red)

## measure time for reduced data
st.time<- Sys.time()
p<-ggplot(df_gs_tidy_plot, aes(x=xval, y=yval)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = zval)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = grey(seq(0,1,l=20))) +
  theme_bw() + ggtitle(i) 
en.time1<- Sys.time()
p
en.time2<- Sys.time()
paste ("time1: ",round(en.time1-st.time,4),"sec")
paste ("time2: ",round(en.time2-st.time,4),"sec")
## around 0.2 sec on my machine

## reduced data with the rectangle
st.time<- Sys.time()
p<-p +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 140, xmax = 1140,
                ymin = 300, ymax = 420), 
            fill=NA, color="red", size=0.5)
en.time1<- Sys.time()
p
en.time2<- Sys.time()
paste ("time1: ",round(en.time1-st.time,4),"sec")
paste ("time2: ",round(en.time2-st.time,4),"sec")
## around 0.6 sec on my machine
```

Thank you for your input - happy for all feedback.

Comment: I bet it is printing many thousands of rectangles on that spot, one for each row of data. Try `annotate("rect", xmin = 140, xmax = 1140, ymin = 300, ymax = 420)`

Answer (score 3):

With your current setup, you have almost a million raster tiles to plot, and with each one, ggplot is plotting another rectangle. With each row, it takes the data (since you are using `aes()`, it assumes the rectangle is drawn using `df_gs_tidy`), ignores it, and maps another rectangle to the coordinates you specified.

You only need one rectangle, so it's more appropriate to use:

```
p<-p +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 140, xmax = 1140, ymin = 300, ymax = 420, 
                   fill=NA, color="red", size=0.5)
```

instead of

```
p<-p +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 140, xmax = 1140,
                ymin = 300, ymax = 420), 
            fill=NA, color="red", size=0.5)
  # Try adding an alpha parameter like 0.01 to see that the rectangle is getting
  # drawn so many times that it looks like alpha = 1.
```

That works much faster on my machine, should be almost identical to the case with no rectangle.